# Autoreload in IPython

Tags: python, autoreload

I have used autoreload before and it worked. For some reason, I am getting error in my new set-up. May be I am missing something.

```
import utility as ut

%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

When I run the above, I get the following error.

```
The autoreload module is not an IPython extension.

UsageError: Line magic function `%autoreload` not found.
```

Comment: Sounds like you named a file `autoreload.py`. Don't name your files that.

Comment: I see a file of that name in my computer. I did not create that file. I must have been created during some installation.